# Python dataframes Cartesian operation on large amount of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-data

I have 2 dataframes, both with around 30k rows and 8 columns, and I need to subtract the values of every row in the first df from values of every row in second df(to compute the Euclidian distance between every pair of rows) which will probably result in a 3d structure of only the differences between every pair of rows. I've tried several approaches but each one takes a very long time to complete. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you share an example of your df and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thank you zipa and MaxU. zipa's solution was correct, but the cdist did it for me. It's fast and tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what is worth, your Cartesian product can be done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4,5,6]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1.assign(key=1), df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
df3
#   A  B
#0  1  4
#1  1  5
#2  1  6
#3  2  4
#4  2  5
#5  2  6
#6  3  4
#7  3  5
#8  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly your resulting data set will contain 900.000.000 rows.

[scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) - is one of the most efficient ways to compute distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.

If you need a cartesian product please see @zipa's answer.